# QT 5.7 Analyze audio output

Tags: c++, qt, audio, fft

Firstly, sorry my english.

Secondly, I have a question:
I'm running QT 5.7 under win7x64. My idea is to create a program that can visualize (eg. Spectrum) audio. But all examples, that i've seen, explaining how to analyze, sound gets from microphone or file that playing in this example.

My purpose is to catch sound that people hear from speakers (or headphones) - all sounds including system beeps, any audio from any players (vlc, winamp, even windows media) - and make audio spectrum.

I've read about QtMultimedia, but as I understand it can get spectrum only from microphone or file.

By now, I have found [bass.dll](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/bass.html), but as I see - it can record from system output device, and then get spectrum (no realtime) - am I right?

Could you explain, how to get audio, that plays from speakers in realtime? Any exapmples will be very good. Or link, at least, where I can read about. (5 hours googling was not really helpful)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to grab a pointer to the default audio endpoint device buffer in Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639816/is-it-possible-to-grab-a-pointer-to-the-default-audio-endpoint-device-buffer-in)

Comment: Your basic problem has nothing to do with spectral analysis. To approach this problem, just write the simplest C++ program you can to tap into your operating system’s audio driver to get a stream from there. The previous commenter pointed you to a Windows approach. [Soundflower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/) is something I’ve used before on Mac, which creates a new virtual soundcard that, if you instruct apps to use, will let you tap into their audio output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I think, I found solution.

For those, who interested, take a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797537/Making-an-Audio-Spectrum-analyzer-with-Bass-dll-Cs) page. There is a simple program, written in C#, that uses Bass.dll and doing exact what I want. Even sources in different language, I hope it can help anyone to write their own application